# Change logging priority of UFW

Tags: linux, systemd, syslog, ufw, journalctl

As far as I can tell (through `journalctl -p 4`) UFW logs all blocked connections as warnings. I'd really like to be able to use that log level for things I actually might want to respond to. Is there any way (short of turning off UFW logging entirely), to log its output at a lower priority, or redirect priorities in journalctl, or some other solution that frees up the noise on priority 4.